# Accessing JPA Data with REST fails No suitable HttpMessageConverter found

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, spring-boot

I have been battling with this for a while and cant find a solution. I am running the SpringBoot guides and the Accessing JPA Data (http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) with REST is not working.

Just downloading it and running it runs fine allowing a GET call to

```
http://localhost:8080/people
```

using POSTMAN. However whenever I try a PUT or POST I get the following error

```
{
 "cause": null,
 "message": "No suitable HttpMessageConverter found to read request body into object of type           class hello.Person from request with content type of text/plain;charset=UTF-8!"
}
```

The json I am passing with the PUT is

```
{
"firstName": "Dave",
"lastName": "Something"
}
```

This is just running the vanilla project with no changes. Lots of the other guide projects work fine so I know MVN, Spring boot etc are working ok.

Have tried a lot of forums but nothing suggested works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 28):

Your POST request has a content type of `text/plain` and the server doesn't know how to convert plain text into a `hello.Person` instance.

You need to tell the server that you're sending JSON by setting the `Content-Type` header of the request to `application/json`

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say that I am explicitly sending application/json in the content type  but spring still seems to think that its getting text/plain.

Answer (score 3):

I used Google Chrome's Postman extension and sent raw JSON `{ "firstName": "Frodo", "lastName": "Baggins" }`. That worked.

Keep in mind to specify the HTTP header `Content-Type: application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

Content-Type:application/json try to remove the space between content-type:* and  application in the header .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selected the

Body->RAW->Json in the Api Client and try it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can select
Body->RAW->Json in the Api Client and try it.
firstly I was using text that's why its giving me error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).